# Error java.lang.NullPointerException to send data to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have two fragment i want to change color of one of them by sending color string to second fragment here is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onclickButton(String SendColor) {
    FragmentTwo fragmentTwo= (FragmentTwo) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.second_fragment);
    fragmentTwo.changeColor(SendColor);

}}
```

And code of fragment number one:

```
public class FragmenyOne extends Fragment {


    private String color;
    private onClickColorButtonListener listener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragmeny_one,container,false);
        Button button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnColor);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.RG);
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
              //  if (selectedId != 0) {
                    RadioButton RB = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);
                    String textRB = RB.getText().toString();
                    switch (textRB) {
                        case "Red":
                            color = "Red";
                            break;
                        case "Yellow":
                            color = "Yellow";
                            break;
                        case "Blue":
                            color = "Blue";
                            break;
                    }

                        listener.onclickButton(color);
               // }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    public interface onClickColorButtonListener{
        void onclickButton(String SendColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);if(context instanceof onClickColorButtonListener)
      listener=(onClickColorButtonListener) context;

    }
}
```

And code of fragment number two:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_two,container,false);
        return view;
    }
    public void changeColor(String color){
        int drawable= Color.WHITE;
        switch (color){
            case "Blue":
                drawable=Color.BLUE;
                break;
            case "Red":
                drawable=Color.RED;
                break;
            case "Yellow":
                drawable=Color.YELLOW;
                break;
        }
        LinearLayout li=(LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.activity_fragment_two);
        li.setBackgroundColor(drawable);
    }
}
```

but android during play app Show me error java.lang.NullPointerException and reference  to listener.onclickButton(color); in fragment number one.

I'd appreciate to help me.

Comment: will you initialise the interface in fragment

Comment: yes i added it in Mainactivity :   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmenyOne.onClickColorButtonListener

Comment: Did u add it in Fragment?

Comment: i only defined it in my fragmentOne as interface OnClickButtonListener

Comment: When the error happens? When you click the button or when you create the activity?

Comment: Can you put the Stack trace in the question?

Comment: When i press button i see error